# Extracting a url from a HYPERLINK in Google Apps Script for Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Say I have `=HYPERLINK("http://google.com/abc","Google")` in `A1` in my spreadsheet and I would like to create a custom Google Apps Script (eg. `=GetURL(A1)`) to return the url portion of this field. What would I have to do to get that working?

Whenever I create a custom script like so

```
function GetURL(input) {
  return input
}
```

All I get is the description of the link, in this case "Google".

Is there any way of actually getting this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an old question, but I had the issue right now.

Turns out that when you add a hyperlink to text in a cell with the spreadsheet web-application, the text gets a rich text value.
(also see [here](https://spreadsheet.dev/add-links-to-a-cell-in-google-sheets-using-apps-script) of how to set a richt text value by Apps Script).

Therefore `range.getFormula();` would get nothing, as there was no formula in the cell.

You can extract the link that is bound to the rich text with:

```
var value = range.getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()
```

Doc for [getRichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getRichTextValue()) and [getLinkUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getLinkUrl())

So the full function function (as Tom Woodward wrote) would look like:

```
 getUrl(input) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(input);
  var value = range.getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
  return value;
}
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUrl(input) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(input);
  var value = range.getFormula(); 
  return value;
}
```

This gets the raw formula `=HYPERLINK("http://google.com/abc","Google"` you can then regex or substring the URL out.

I did have to put the ss reference in like `=getUrl("A1")` with A1 in quotes to make it work.